# Can I use ivy:install to install a zip file from maven to a local Ivy repository?

Tags: maven, ivy

I have a dependency on the `dojo-1.9.3-distribution.zip` found in Maven:

```
<dependency org="org.dojotoolkit" name="dojo" rev="1.9.3" conf="dependencies->default">
    <artifact name="dojo" type="zip" ext="zip" m:classifier="distribution" />
</dependency>
```

Since our company uses a local Ivy repository, I'd like to use `ivy:install` to install this zip to our local repository.

I've tried using the following declaration:

```
<ivy:install organisation="org.dojotoolkit" module="dojo" revision="1.9.3-distribution" from="${from.resolver}" to="${to.resolver}" transitive="true" overwrite="true" haltonfailure="false" />
```

However, it keeps trying to download a jar, not the zip. Is there a way I can tell `ivy:install` to download a zip? I use Ivy 2.2.0.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with IVY but you should try to use a classifier (used in maven)..?

Comment: @khmarbaise I've tried using that, but as far as I can see, simply adding the xmlns definition for maven to my ant build file project definition and m:classifier to the ivy:install doesn't work.